# Dúvida com LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, expressões-lambda, linq-to-entities

Como ficaria essa consulta em LINQ to Entities:

```
SELECT      COUNT(cont) qtde_resp
        ,   pergunta
        ,   resposta
FROM        pesq_respostas
WHERE       id_pesquisa = 9
        AND Tipo IN ('Intervalo', 'SimNao')
GROUP BY    pergunta
        ,   resposta
```

Tentei fazer da seguinte forma:

```
dynamic countTag = (from a in context.PesqRespostaModel
                                    where a.id_pesquisa == idPesquisa
                                    group new { a } by new {  a.resposta, a.pergunta } into gr
                                    select new
                                    {
                                        gr.Key.pergunta,
                                        gr.Key.resposta,
                                        Count = gr.Select(x => x.a.cpf).Distinct().Count()

                                    }).ToList();
```

Porém, dá o seguinte erro:

[image: erro]

mas esse campo existe, tanto no banco quanto na classe.

Segue meu modelo:

```
[Table("pesq_respostas")]
public class PesqRespostaModel
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int id_resposta { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int id_pesquisa{ get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "pergunta")]
    [StringLength(128, ErrorMessage = "O campo Resposta pode ter mo máximo 128 caracteres.")]
    public string pergunta { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "resposta")]
    [StringLength(48, ErrorMessage = "O campo Resposta pode ter mo máximo 48 caracteres.")]
    public string resposta { get; set; }

    public string tipo { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "cpf")]
    [StringLength(14, ErrorMessage = "O campo Resposta pode ter mo máximo 14 caracteres.")]
    public string cpf { get; set; }            

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "data")]        
    public DateTime data { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Ao invés de ter `group new { a } by new {  a.resposta, a.pergunta } into gr` coloque apenas `group a by new { a.resposta, a.pergunta } into gr`.

Comment: João, fiz como vc disse, mas deu o mesmo erro.

Comment: Pode colocar o seu modelo na sua questão?

Comment: atualizei, colocando o modelo

Comment: De onde vem o objeto `Project2` que é indicado no erro? E a propriedade `resposta` na cláusula `where` se não está lá?

Comment: João, nao sei de onde vem esse project2, acredito que o framework cria isso, estranho. Tem a ver com o Count, quando eu removo Count, tudo funciona.

Comment: Altere o `Count()` para o seguinte: `Count = gr.Count()` e valide se já funciona.